# Need a time management solution

Tags: time-management

I'm looking for a pc app that runs in the background and collates simple information about applications im running. Hopefully including the opened project (whereby visual studio includes the title of the project in the window title).
Also if it could include periods of inactivity that would be useful.

It's intended to help me fill out the dreaded timesheets!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like the exact situation that [TimeSnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/) was designed for.

From the website:

> What is it?
>
> TimeSnapper is an Automatic Screenshot
>   Journal
>
> It runs in the background of your
>   computer, taking screenshots of your
>   desktop every few seconds all week
>   long.

Note: I'm not connected to these guys, not even as a customer. Well, I do read the blog. :-)

Comment: +1 very interesting!
Seems a bit 'brute force' though, so i'll leave the question open for some more suggestions.

Comment: TimeSnapper is wonderful. It also analyzes which window has focus, and how long it is since you last pressed a key or moved the mouse - so it can report on how long you spent in which app and how much time you spent at your desk.

http://www.timesnapper.com/image/v2.4/ProgramStatisticsReport.png

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Rescuetime](http://rescuetime.com)

Answer (score 1):

I rather like [Slife](http://www.slifelabs.com/), it gives me enough information to make timesheets.

Comment: Throws up errors when disconnect from internet "can not resolve hostname" - these should be silently logged, frictionless software. Does not work with Google Chrome. #fail

Answer (score 1):

Try out [ProcrastiTracker](http://procrastitracker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ptm.sourceforge.net/ It tracks how much time is spent in each application but doesn't keep track of the window titles. You can also create your own tasks. It will prompt you anywhere from every 10 minutes to an hour to see if your still working on the same task, if you don't click the still continuing button it will go to idle.